# openvpn error outines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate:ca md too weak

Tags: networking, openvpn, ssl, certificates

On Ubunto 16 I've configured openVPN with `password with Certificate (TSL)`

my config file is:

```
dev tun
remote XX.XX.XXX.X
ca ca.crt
cert user_name.crt
key user_name.key
ns-cert-type server
```

It does work well.

My workstation has Ubuntu 19.04 and I can't connect, I get the error:

> Thu Oct 17 00:01:15 2019 WARNING: file 'user_name.key' is group or
>   others accessible Thu Oct 17 00:01:15 2019 OpenVPN 2.4.6
>   x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11]
>   [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on May 14 2019 Thu Oct 17 00:41:15 2019
>   library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019, LZO 2.10 Thu Oct 17
>   00:01:15 2019 WARNING: --ns-cert-type is DEPRECATED.  Use
>   --remote-cert-tls instead. Thu Oct 17 00:01:15 2019 OpenSSL: error:140AB18E:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate:ca md too weak Thu
>   Oct 17 00:41:15 2019 Cannot load certificate file user_name.crt Thu Oct
>   17 00:01:15 2019 Exiting due to fatal error

user_name.crt and all other files are located at `/etc/openvpn`

Is there some differences between Ubuntu 16 and 19 regarding VPN certificates?
Or is it possible that because I first connected (successfully) with the Ubunto 16, now the VPN server is only accepted connections from this machine/user?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some differences between Ubuntu 16 and 19 regarding VPN certificates?

Ubuntu 19  has increased the requirements for accepted certificates in general, not only for VPN. Make sure that you have for an RSA certificate at least a key size of 2048 and that at least SHA-2 is used for the signature.

Comment: Yes all the certificates, user, passwords are the same in Ubuntu 16 and 19. Does this means that I should ask for new certificates to use in Ubuntu 19? On windows 10, those certificates also work.

Comment: @Rnu: `ca md too weak` says that the signature algorithm for the certificate is to weak. While the details about the specific certificates is unknown you might need to get new ones.